# Change Texture Resolution inside Blender

Tags: resolution

Is it possible to change the texture res within blender? I have 4K textures which I want to render in 2K for a preview rendering. Do I have to reload the textures in the material every time? my scene is big and heavy so I can't make 2 different ones for all materials without spending hours on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Render Properties > [Simplify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/render_settings/simplify.html) feature:

[image: Simplify]

Moreover since 2.80 you can resize image directly in Image or UV Editor:

[image]

Note that you'll need to save (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) the image afterwards.

Comment: can't find the texture limit in Render Simplify in Blender 3 anymore

Comment: @ina it's only for cycles .. but I've submitter suggestion https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/46A0/